# ASP.NET MVC2 - Visual Studio 2010 Pro Unit Testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

Good Afternoon,

I have a full pro. version of Visual Studio 2010. I have created an application. I would now like to automatically generate some basic tests, is this possible?

I have checked out asp.net/mvc but they seem to be creating them manually. I have also read up about nUnit.

Many Thanks, 
J Harley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio can automatically create a Test project for you, but you will have to write the tests yourself. I really recommend looking into NUnit, it is very powerful and I tend to prefer it compared to MSTest. NUnit also integrates very nicely with ReSharper.